# Oracle 12.1 performance on NVL and Left Outer Join

Tags: oracle, database-performance, query-performance

We have a query  as follows :

```
  select * from table_1 where
        NVL ( date_col_1, date_col_2 ) <= table2.date_col_3(+)
```

This query is undergoing performance problem.

Can somebody verify/answer the following :

1. Even if we have index on date_col_1 and date_col_2, the index will not be used because we are using a function (NVL). Correct ?
2. All the rows of table will be retrieved, even if they don't match due to fact it is left outer join. Correct ?
3. Will a function based index be best suited here ?

Comment: Please correct your example query: it doesn't have table2. And the predicate you showed is very very strange for left join.

Comment: And describe in details what do you want to get really. You can provide test data and test query using `with test_table as (select 1 from dual) select .. from test_table ...`

Comment: run an explain plan and post the results.  Also nobody should be using legacy (+) syntax these days